# sorting date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have dates stored in my column as

```
 Wednesday, November 21, 2018
 Wednesday, August 22, 2018
 Wednesday, August 22, 2018
 Wednesday, August 22, 2018
 Wednesday, August 15, 2018
 Tuesday, November 27, 2018
 Tuesday, November 06, 2018
 Monday, November 19, 2018
```

I am using

```
 ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(100), submissionDate, 101) DESC
```

but its not giving me column in sorted way. My column is NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: is it varchar??? you should have stored it as DATE

Comment: Convert formatted dates to dates. Then format them on demand.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That convert code is product specific.)

Comment: Why are you converting in the ORDER BY instead of using the submissionDate directly? What sort order do you want (varchar sorts alphabetically)?

Comment: The conversion `CONVERT(varchar(100), submissionDate, 101)` will only do what you want if submissionDate were actually a column of type datetime. It converts a datetime to a string in the desired format (here the format `101`)

Comment: my column is nvarchar(max)

Comment: You probably don't what to hear this: if possible, you should definitely change the type of that column to date or datetime. Nvarchar (even worse, max) is a terrible format to store dates.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are stuck with the column type nvarchar**, you can convert the value to a date with something like this:

```
SELECT *, submissionDate
, convert(date
          , right(submissionDate, len(submissionDate) 
            - charindex(',', submissionDate))
          , 107) as my_date
FROM your_table
ORDER BY my_date
```

Or just

```
SELECT submissionDate
FROM your_table
ORDER BY convert(date
          , right(submissionDate, len(submissionDate) 
            - charindex(',', submissionDate))
          , 107)
```

The conversion is a bit cumbersome because of your date format. Sql Server does not seem to have a matching built-in format. So **we get rid of the day of the week** (Monday,..) by removing the part before the first comma and then the result complies with format `107 (Mon dd, yyyy)`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is pretty good about recognizing arcane formats as dates, but not good enough for this situation.  I think that `stuff()` makes this simpler:

```
select convert(date,
               stuff(datestr, 1, charindex(',', datestr) + 1, '')
              )
from (values ('Wednesday, November 21, 2018')) v(datestr)
```